# Extract resolution from string

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk

I have the following string

```
Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5238 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 30k tbn, 58 tbc
```

and I try to extract `1280x720`,

I used

```
sed -r 's/.+([0-9]{3,5})x([0-9]{3,5}).+/\1x\2/'
```

but it will only return `280x720`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

grep may help:

```
grep -Po '\d{3,5}x\d{3,5}'
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not as succinct, but it will work for 
[much more](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html)
than the dimensions.

```sh
$ eval $(ffprobe -v 0 -show_streams -print_format flat=h=0:s=_ foo.mp4)

$ echo $stream_0_width
1280

$ echo $stream_0_height
720
```